# Remove certain spaces in print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried searching this but the solutions either didn't fit what I needed (`sep=""`) or work (+). My code is as follows:

```
present_board([4, 3, 1, 2])

def present_board(board):
    print('Nim:')
    i = 1
    for elem in board:
        print(i,'\b'':',elem * 'X ')
        i += 1
    pass
```

I want it to print like:

```
1: X X X X
```

instead of:

```
1 : X X X X
```

Comment: Why are you printing a backspace `\b` character?

Comment: The comma separator inside the `print` is the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String formatting helps:

```
def present_board(board):
    print('Nim:')
    for i, elem in enumerate(board, 1):
        print('{}:'.format(i), elem * 'X ')

present_board([4, 3, 1, 2])
```

Output:

```
Nim:
1: X X X X 
2: X X X 
3: X 
4: X X
```

I addition, `enumerate` helps your increment your counter automatically.

#### Python 3.6+ only

Use a f-string:

```
def present_board(board):
    print('Nim:')
    for i, elem in enumerate(board, 1):
        print(f'{i}:', elem * 'X ')

present_board([4, 3, 1, 2])
```